# PHP function not working some times. No error found

Tags: php, oop

I have called a function in php to do a query. It worked once as expected. But, when I tried to call it again it is not working. I'm not getting any errors.

Exactly my goal is to remove subscription of a subscriber who has not payed. I added the function to check if a subscriber is payed or not. If he hasn't payed then if he has a subscription, it should be deleted from database.

```php
// function to remove subscription if he hasn't payed
public static function removeSubscriptionNotPayed(){
        global $db;

        $subscribers = Subscriber::allSubscribers();

        foreach($subscribers as $subscriber){
          $id = $subscriber->id;
          $payment = $subscriber->payment;

          if($payment == 0){
            if($db->query("DELETE FROM subscription WHERE subscriber_id = {$id}")){
              return true;
            }else{
              return false;
            }
          }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you loop and immediately return in the loop?

Comment: I tried getting *return* out of the loop. But the result remains same

Comment: All of this seems like it could be done in a single SQL query. I do not understand the reason to have 2 PHP functions for this.

Comment: Yes. Now I can meet this requirement with one function. But the problem is it is only working once.

Comment: Since you are returning seemingly prematurely after having done one iteration through the loop, is it not possible when you call the function the second time you are trying to process the same subscriber_id whose subscriptions have already been deleted and hence the error?

Comment: When you say "it is not working" and "no error found", aren't these contradictory? What indication do you have that it is not working? A bad return code from $db->query? Isn't that an error? Why don't you tell the world all the pertinent information you have?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this all in one query with:

```
DELETE FROM subscription 
JOIN subscribers ON subscribers.id = subscription.subscriber_id  
WHERE payment = 0
```

The most likely reason why your current function produces no tangible results is because the first subscriber on your list probably has no subscriptions in the database. Because you immediately return from the function you will always only handle one and the same subscriber.